# Bootstrap accordion elements won't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make an accordion menu in Bootstrap.  Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/ra2crej1/

While the elements do open, for some reason they do not close on click.  How do I fix this?

I'm using the code from the documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse), but for some reason in JSFiddle it does not behave as it does in the docs.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you don't have the bootstrap.js file being loaded in anywhere.
You want to have the bootstrap.js file being loaded and in the header of your document go ahead and add this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.collapse').collapse
});

</script>
```

here's a working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ra2crej1/2/

and here's a working jsfiddle with your content:
http://jsfiddle.net/ra2crej1/3/

Comment: I loaded `bootstrap.min.js` as an external resource.  Does this not suffice?  The [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) say that one should only load one of `bootstrap.min.js` and `bootstrap.js`.

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle with the desired behavior?  I added your script to the `<head>` of my document here: http://jsfiddle.net/ra2crej1/, but it doesn't seem to have been fixed.

Comment: I added a working jsfiddle using the content from the bootstrap docs.

Comment: Here's a working jsfiddle with the content you were trying to have added as well: http://jsfiddle.net/ra2crej1/3/